# Trigger using DataContext.ValueChanged does not work if using Dispatcher.BeginInvoke, only with Invoke

Tags: wpf, multithreading, animation, dispatcher

This is getting my crazy. I have the following animation on a TextBlock (inside a DataGrid):

```
<TextBlock.Style>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock" >
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.ValueChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type xcdg:DataCell}}}" Value="True">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard >
                            <ColorAnimation AutoReverse="True" From="{StaticResource NormalForeground}" To="{StaticResource ModifiedForeground}" Duration="0:0:0.25" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground.Color" FillBehavior="Stop" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</TextBlock.Style>
```

The value updates come from another thread so I'm using the Dispatcher. If I update the value using:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(propertychange notification of the viewmodel)
```

Everything works. If I update the value using:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(propertychange notification of the viewmodel)
```

The animation does not work anymore ... any ideas¿?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that `BeginInvoke` is pretty much depreciated, in favour of async/await style coding which was introduced in .NET 4.5.

Functions starting with `Begin` are usually written using an older asynchronous style that was introduced in .NET 1.1, and in my mind, seems clunky compared to using the newer async/await style.

You can easily tell the styles apart:

- Older asynchronous functions introduced in .NET 1.1 usually start with the letters `Begin-`.
- Newer functions compatible with the async/await style, introduced in .NET 4.5, usually end in the letters `-Async`.

If you really want to use asynchronous calls, base it on async/await, and use something like this instead:

`Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(async () => { Title = await getTitle(); });`

I'd recommend reading up on async/await, it's the best way to write fast, snappy, responsive user apps. If you are using Windows 8.1, it's the only way, as if you spend more than 50 milliseconds blocking the GUI thread, the OS will complain.

Comment: I know but we are working in an application developed in .Net 4 as it has to be supported in XP. Next time maybe.

Comment: Sorry to hear, that's a bit of a limitation.